# Colimit of coproduct

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors

Let $g := \underset{c\in ob(\mathcal{C})}{\coprod} \frac{\mathcal{F}(c)}{\sim}$
for a small category $\mathcal{C}$ and $g \in Top$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation $x\sim\mathcal{F}(f)x$ for $x\in\mathcal{F}(c_{1})\ni$

$$f:c_{1}\rightarrow c_{2}$$
so
$$\mathcal{F}(f)x\in\mathcal{F}(c_{2})$$

with functor $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow Top$.

This constructs the canonical map $$\varphi_{\mathcal{F}}(c):\mathcal{F\Longrightarrow g}$$

with natural transformation:

$$\varphi_{\mathcal{F}}:\mathcal{F\Longrightarrow \mathcal{F}_g}$$

So:
$$g=\underset{\mathcal{C}}{colim}\mathcal{F}$$

I understand that a coproduct is the colimit over the diagram that consists of just two objects. So is the reason that $g$ is the colimit just precisely by construction where the diagram here would successively have $f$ edges between nodes of $c$?

Is there something additional that would need to be demonstrated to substantiate the final statement (that $g$ is $\underset{\mathcal{C}}{colim \mathcal{F}}$)?

Comment: I think your $\mathcal F$ is a functor from a certain domain category to the category of sets; but what is $d$? What is $\mathcal F_g$? Also: a colimit has a universal property that defines it up to isomorphism. Once $g$ satisfies that property, it's the colimit.

Comment: @Fosco Thanks- it should just be $g$, $d$ was a typo which has been corrected.

Comment: It seems you really want to dualise [Borceux I, 2.8.1]; but it also seems you are a bit confused about notation and terminology: proceed one step at a time. :)